# Meaning of an ergodic trajectory

Tags: ergodicity

I'm trying to understand the concept of an *ergodic trajectory* in the context of dynamical systems. I think that I have a reasonable idea of the word "ergodic".

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688345/understanding-ergodicity-and-what-an-ergodic-system-is) links to a Wikipedia article

> ergodicity expresses the idea that a point of a moving system, ..., will eventually visit all parts of the space that the system moves in...

If I take a typical trajectory of the Rössler attractor, it seems clear that it doesn't visit all parts of the 3D space, but it does visit all parts of the attractor. Moreover, almost all trajectories visit all parts of the attractor, so [almost] no trajectory has anything special to tell me about the attractor, compared to any other trajectory.

Is this what is meant by ergodic trajectory?